# Display buildings at any zoom level using google maps javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with the google maps javascript api and would like to display the building overlays at any zoom level. Right now I am developing a map for my company and in order to see the entire campus on our displays I have to set the zoom level to 16. Right now it looks like google only displays the building overlays at zoom level 17 or greater. Please advise if there is a way to override the default display of the building overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to enable the 3d building on any zoom level. Only disable 3d buildings (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-maps-js-api-v3/HVYNrG_2tLs/9o6Jff7CiXkJ). You can test this out using a visual google maps styler (http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

Did you try this

```
map.setZoom(15);
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
```

Comment: Can you add additional details and explanation?

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue where I want to see the building overlays.